# Is javascript timer events run in bulk when logging in after screen lock?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I know that timer events will be throttled to execute once in a second when browser tab is not active, likewise is there any scenario timer events will be stored and executed in bulk at once? (eg: when logging in a locked session)

Comment: That entirely depends on the browser, and the easiest way to determine is to perform a test

Comment: I don't observe any throttling on my desktop Chrome

Comment: setInterval(function(){console.log(new Date())},500); Please execute this code and move to the other tab and come again. You can see that print will be once in a second intead of twice in a second.

Comment: I didnt get bulk execution when logging in, but I am asking is there any scenarios in which browsers will behave like that

Answer (score 0):

When you block the thread - all timers will get "clamped" in Opera 12.x (Presto) and Firefox:

```
setTimeout( function () { var x = Date.now(); console.log(x) }, 1000);
setTimeout( function () { var x = Date.now(); console.log(x) }, 9000);
alert('Please wait at least 10 seconds, then press OK');
```

but will **not** clamp in IE or Chrome (and, probably, same behavior will be observed in Opera 14+ (Webkit/Blink) and Safari).

---

Compare:

```
Opera 
1371598885051
1371598885051

Firefox
1371598994797
1371598994798

Chrome
1371599039369
1371599047371

IE10  
1371598756046 
1371598763050
```